# Setting an <li> element as "active" on onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, html-lists

I am making a fly-out menu with 11 items that can be moused over on the left and a content box to the right.  On mouseover it works fine but I want the first element "Overview" to be set as 'active' on page load giving the users a description of what the other elements are.  I have tried sticking "onload="document.getElementById('switch1').focus();"" in an inline for the desired li tag, earlier in the Javascript, and inline in the body tag to no avail.  Perhaps I am not adding it properly?  Are there better solutions to getting that element highlighted?  Any help would be amazing!  Thank you in advance.

```
function init() {
document.getElementById('switch1').focus();
}
window.onload = init;
            $(document).ready(function() {
        switches = $('#switches > li');
        slides = $('#slides > div');
        switches.each(function(idx) {
                $(this).data('slide', slides.eq(idx));
            }).hover(
            function() {

                switches.removeClass('active');
                slides.removeClass('active');             
                $(this).addClass('active');  
                $(this).data('slide').addClass('active');
            });
        });

.4Column{
width: 250px;
height: 239px;
float:left;
margin-left:30px;}

#switches .hover {
background-position: left center;
display: block;}

#switches .active {
font-weight: bold;
background-position:left bottom;}

#switches li {
padding-left:10px;
background-image:url(../images/ManageArrows.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:20px;
width:230px;}

#slides div {
display: none;}

#slides div.active {
    display: block;}

.IndySlide{
    width: 336px;
height: 255px;
float:left;
background-color:#FFF;}

#switch1{
padding-left:10px;
background-image:url(../images/ManageArrows.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width: 230px;
height: 20px;}

#switch1 .active{
font-weight: bold;
background-position:left bottom;}


<div class="4Column" style="width:250px; height:239px; float:left; margin-left:0px;">
    <div id="featured">
        <ul id="switches" class="active">
            <li id="switch1">Overview</li>
            <li id="switch2">Agriculture</li>
            <li id="switch3">Forests</li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="4Column" style="width:335px; height:255px; float:left; margin-left:20px;">
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="IndySlide"><!-- Overview -->
            <p>This is a list of the most amazingestest links on the DNR baby sites.</p>
        </div>
    <div class="IndySlide" style="background-image:url(images/cowbg.png);"><!-- Agriculture -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://dnr.alaska.gov/ag/ag_calendar_2012.htm">Ag event calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://dnr.alaska.gov/ag/ag_bac.htm">Ag board meetings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/forestrybg.png);width:336px; height:255px;"><!-- Forests -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://forestry.alaska.gov/stateforests.htm">State Forests</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://forestry.alaska.gov/burn/">Burn permits</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://forestry.alaska.gov/fire/current.htm">Fire information</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    switches = $('#switches > li');
    slides = $('#slides > div');
    switches.each(function(idx) {
            $(this).data('slide', slides.eq(idx));
        }).hover(
        function() {

            switches.removeClass('active');
            slides.removeClass('active');             
            $(this).addClass('active');  
            $(this).data('slide').addClass('active');
        });

    switches.first().trigger('mouseover');
});
```

I had mistakenly put 'hover' originally, not mouseover.  Hover is CSS, mouseOver is the JavaScript event.  My apologies!  But that will work.  You could also call it by name.  The reason you would want to do it this way though, is because you might change the name of the class some day, and this way you wouldn't have to update your JavaScript to preserve functionality.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work.  Is it possible to call it out by name (switch1)?

Comment: See the edit.  I changed `switches.first().trigger('hover')`, which was WRONG to the correct `switches.first().trigger('mouseover')`, which works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the init function inside the

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    init();
    // rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make this active in the CSS? Add a class `.sel` to #switch1 and a similar '.sel' to the first `#slides > div` ~ `#slides > div:first`. Then through the Jquery, on the click event for the left hand links, you can add the '.sel' class to the new selected links / content panel to make them active.

Comment: Thank you!  I am new to jquery and javascript.  How would you write that?